# AngularJs - Hide on ng-init

Tags: angularjs

I am using the ng-init directive to initialize. I have a button (btnPrevious) that should not be displayed at startup, but only on the call of the ng-click. How can I initialize the application with the button hidden and then display on ng-click?

```js
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['angular-loading-bar']);

MyApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope) {

    $scope.getFirstQuestion = function () {
        $http.get('/URL')
            .success(function (qst) {
                $scope.question = qst;
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = error.message;
                console.log($scope.status);
            });
    }
        
    $scope.getNextQuestion = function (p, r) {
        
        //
    }

    $scope.getPreviousQuestion = function () {

        //
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" class="container">
    <div ng-controller="MyController" ng-init="getFirstQuestion()">
        <h3>{{question.Description}}</h3>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="r in question.Answers">
                <input type="button" id="{{r.Id}}" value="{{r.Description}}"
                       ng-click='getNextQuestion(question.Id, r.Id)' class="btn btn-default" />
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input type="button" ng-click='getPreviousQuestion()' name="btnPrevious" value="Previous" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please put part of your code or create plunker.

Comment: You Should Update your Query with a Plunker or Code Buddy .. Where i can Lift the Down Vote .. see  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .. if you wanna quick help you need to post the Issue Clearly with your research part

Comment: You really need to post code for your current implementation at a minimum. Even better would be posting how you have tried to accomplish it already and any issues your having from that.

Comment: consider not using ngInit https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit